# Magento export products to google products search and shopzilla

Tags: google, magento

I have a new store on Magento, is there a solution or script that can help me submit my feeds to Google products search and Shopzilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a free service that made me do exactly what you are looking for and even more. Its an extension on magento see this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rinkarto/extension/6771/feed_manager_version_1_1_2

Answer (score 0):

There is a Magento-developed extension for Google Shopping submission.

[Link to Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Magento+Core/extension/6887/mage_googleshopping)

Comment: Thanks. Does it work for shopzilla too?